# Assign values to a dereferenced void pointer

Tags: c

I'm doing a class in c++ that supports any kind of variable to help me in a future project. The thing is, when I try to assign a value to a `void*` variable, I get the error: `void*` is not a pointer-to-object type. Here is the code:

```
int main (void) {
    void* a;
    int x;
    a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    x = 120;
    ((int)(*a)) = x;
    printf("%d",((int)*a));
    free(a);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I see it like I am trying to assign the value of x in the memory block reserved for a. I want that the value stored in x be stored in the memory block of a. Can any1 help me?

Answer (score 9):

You probably want to do:

```
void* a;
int x;
a = malloc(sizeof(int));
x = 120;
*(int*)a = x;
printf("%d", * (int*)a);
free(a);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're making it too complicated.  Just cast `a` to be an `int *`, or better yet declare `a` as int * to start with.

```
int x = 120;
int * a ;
// now just cast the result from malloc as int*
if((a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int))) == NULL){ //ALWAYS check
   exit(-1);
}
*a = x;
```

There are slicker ways to do similar things in C++, but you appear to be primarily caught up in pointer syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you must cast `a` to the appropriate pointer type and *then* de-reference it. Secondly, use a template- that's what they're for. Thirdly, malloc and free is baaaad, OK? Don't. If you think that this is good code, you need serious remedial C++. Fourthly, this is already done- `boost::any` serves this purpose.

Comment: This is why I hate "C/C++".

Comment: @Charlie: yeah, but he didn't say "C ∩ C++" nor "C ∪ C++".

Comment: No, but he then uses stuff that's only C.

Comment: @Charlie: That doesn't make it C. He clearly states that he's going to put it in a class, in a class in C++, and he only tags C++. I think it's pretty clear what language he's discussing.

Comment: it doesn't really answered my question.. malloc and free can be easily replaced. boost::any ins't even a C++ standard class. This problem has only the purpose of knowledge. Its important to know how things work before use a real class to understand whats going on on my program..

Answer (score 3):

You need the cast as `*(int*)(a) = x;`.

Comment: I think, this might break strict aliasing rule as `(int*)(a)` is not yet a lvalue.

Comment: @iammilind can you pls elaborate? what do you mean by `break strict aliasing rule`?

Comment: @user, refer this [What is the strict aliasing rule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Answer (score 0):

There are other elegant ways to assign a variable of different types. For your current question you can follow the standard way as,

```
int* const a = new int;
//...
*a = 120;
//...
delete a;
```

Or just for this problem specifically,

```
int a = 120; // simple
```

[Note: In your current solution if you do,

```
*((int*)(a)) = x;
```

it might be breaking strict aliasing rule.]

Comment: Well, that completely avoids his question about malloc and void *.

Comment: @Charlie, it's evident that whatever OP is doing is not correct and seemingly doesn't need `malloc/void*`.