# Assigning values to a void*

Tags: c, fread

In C the fread() has a parameter of a void* which will be assigned the value of the next chunk of bytes being read from the file. My understanding is that a void* is used so that several data types can be given to the function. However when I try to use this type of parameter in my own function it seems that assigning a value to a void* is not allowed.

For example:

```
void* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
int n = 5;
*ptr = n; //Error here
```

This gives an error saying that void is not assignable. If this is the case then how does it work in the fread()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign values to a dereferenced void pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081288/assign-values-to-a-dereferenced-void-pointer)

Comment: @Barmar I saw this, I did not see a satisfactory answer and no explanation was given to why it can be used in fread() and not other functions.

Comment: Those functions contain code similar to the answer there. They cast the pointer to an appropriate type before dereferencing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of `fread` is none of your business, but presumably it will create a `char`-like pointer from your void pointer and assume that the pointer you provided was created from a valid, non-null object pointer. For example:

**You:**

```
int data[10];

fread(data, sizeof(int), 10, fp);
```

**fread:**

```
size_t fread(void * ptr, size_t sz, size_t nmemb, FILE * fp)
{
    char * dst = ptr;
    // read data into *dst in chunks of sz bytes
    // ...
}
```

This makes sense because you can treat any object as an array of characters, but passing a `void *` argument is simpler since the conversions from object to void pointers are implicit and don't need explicit casts.

Comment: `fread` probably uses `memcpy` instead of messing with individual chars,and so doesn't need that cast.

Comment: it's probably written in assembler :)  but implementations written in portable C are not unlike your code, converting the void* into a writable pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this: `int* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));`, or recast it by `*(int*)(ptr) = n`.

Comment: I want it to be able to handle any of the raw data types not just 1

Answer (score 0):

void by definition is not assignable.
You might do it this way:

```
*(int*)ptr = n;
```

But basically you (probably) make mistake in a way you allocate memory. i would recommend this:

```
int* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
int n = 5;
*ptr = n;
```

Answer (score 0):

`fread()` uses something like `memcpy()` to copy the data from a buffer that was filled using `read()` or `_read()` or `READ()` or something platform specific like that.